# HtmlAgilityPack getting id of parrent node

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, html-agility-pack

Given the snippet of html and code bellow if you know part of the src e.g. 'FileName' how do you get the post ID of the parent div this could be higher up the dom tree  and there could be 0, 1 or many src's with the same 'FileName'

I'm after "postId_19701770"

I've attempted to follow this [page](https://html-agility-pack.net/knowledge-base/8948895/using-xpath-and-htmlagilitypack-to-find-all-elements-with-innertext-containing-a-specific-word-or-words) and this [page](https://html-agility-pack.net/parent-node) I get Error  CS1061  'HtmlNodeCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ParentNode'

```
namespace GetParent
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var html =
@"<body>
<div id='postId_19701770' class='b-post'>
            <h1>This is <b>bold</b> heading</h1>
            <p>This is <u>underlined</u> paragraph <div src='example.com/FileName_720p.mp4' </div></p>
</div>
        </body>";

            var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
            string keyword = "FileName";
            var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[text()[contains(., '" + keyword + "')]]");

            var parentNode = node.ParentNode;

            Console.WriteLine(parentNode.Name);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason your code is not working is because you are looking up a `ParentNode` of a collection of nodes. You need to select a single node and then look up its parent.

You can search all the nodes (collection) by `src` as well that contains the data you are looking for. Once you have the collection, you can search each of those nodes to see which one you need or select the `First()` one from that collection to get its Parent.

```
var html =
@"<body>
<div id='postId_19701770' class='b-post'>
<h1>This is <b>bold</b> heading</h1>
<p>This is <u>underlined</u> paragraph <div src='example.com/FileName_720p.mp4' </div></p>
</div>
</body>";

var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
string keyword = "FileName";
var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@src, '" + keyword + "')]");

var parent = node.First().ParentNode; //node is a collection so get the first node for ex.
Console.WriteLine(parent.GetAttributeValue("id", string.Empty));

// Prints
postId_19701770
```

Instead of looking up "all" nodes, you can search specifically for 1 node via `SelectSingleNode` method

```
var singleNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"//*[contains(@src, '" + keyword + "')]");
Console.WriteLine(singleNode.ParentNode.GetAttributeValue("id", string.Empty));

// prints 
postId_19701770
```

Comment: Hi Jawad In the context of the example it  works so thank you. Is ParentNode just the immediate parent or can a condition be added like "parent.???("//div[starts-with(@id,'postId_')]" );" or regex "postId_\d*" so it filters up the dom tree?

Comment: @Holly `ParentNode` is just the immediate parent of any node. You can write a recursive method that can go up all the way to the top while searching for required node/text or whatever it is you are looking for.  Another way would be to find a node with postId_* and then search all its children to find if there is a node with attribute src and value = keyword.